# Magento - Get all associated products of a grouped product

Tags: magento

I want the "grouped product" table to be shown in the category list view. But how can this be done? So far I've only found some old <1.4 solutions, I'm currently using 1.6.2.

Comment: Try: http://www.webpoint0.com/blog/magento-add-grouped-products-price-table-to-category-view/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that

```
$product_typeinstance = $product->getTypeInstance(true);
$collection = $product_typeinstance->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                            'manufacturer',
                            'price',
                            'special_price',
                            'is_salable',
                            'or_any_attribute_you_require',
                    ))
                    ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
                    ->setPositionOrder()
                    ->addStoreFilter($product_typeinstance->getStoreFilter($product))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => $product_typeinstance->getStatusFilters($product)))
                    //->setPage(0, 5) // if you require to limit number of product
                    ;
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                // do what you want. ex. echo $item>getPrice();
            }
```